# Hudson installation proxy failed

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, domain, hudson

I have a fresh installation of Hudson, default directories and all that. I have been following 
This Guide

I have followed what it said, up to the actual 000-default modification. I'm sort of stuck on this part.

This is what I have as my 000-default file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName name
    ServerAlias name
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

ProxyPass /var/lib/hudson/  http://mydomain:8080/hudson/
ProxyPassReverse /var/lib/hudson/ http://mydomain:8080/hudson/
</VirtualHost>
```

My proxy.conf looks like:

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Allow from [mynetwork]
</Proxy>
```

As the guide says, I would like to access hudson by navigating to mydomain/hudson

instead of mydomain:8080/

so far, I have changed it so that 
mydomain:8080/ results in a 404,

mydomain:8080/hudson actually takes me to hudson

but mydomain/hudson results in an apache error that says:

```
 File does not exist: /etc/apache2/var
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to change your ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse lines to something like:

```
ProxyPass /hudson/  http://mydomain:8080/hudson/
ProxyPassReverse /hudson/ http://mydomain:8080/hudson/
```

Here's the Apache documentation:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Comment: It ended up being that I had to restart my server, I was restarting hudson and apache, but aparently the whole thing needed to be restarted.

Now, when I go to mydomain/hudson, it re-directs me to mydomain:8080/hudson, so that works. 

Thanks!